# SQL return the minium value from multiple keys

Tags: sql, min

This is the code I have written so far for my query:

```
     select
         workorderkey,
         WarrantyRoutingStep, 
         StepOrder
     from tblFAWOWarrantyRoutingsOEM WarrantyRoutings
     where 
workorderkey=220870 and --fyi i do not want to do this
StepCompleteDate IS NULL
```

The result is this

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8kD6.jpg)

How do I get it to look like this, so it returns only the row with the minimum value in the StepOrder column)? Note that I don't just want the results for workorderkey 220870; I want it to group and return a single result for each workorderkey - just entered that filter for testing.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QwVr.jpg)

Please forgive the pictures instead of text for the table results. First time poster, month-long viewer. Just started writing SQL a few weeks ago.

Comment: did you try GROUP BY workorderkey HAVING StepOrder = MIN(StepOrder) ?

Comment: Please, provide input and output without external links.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 .....

Comment: Please tag databse used mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc.? how to ask a good question.  you where almost there but here are some other tips: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score 1):

If your dbms supports window functions it is easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       select
          workorderkey,
          WarrantyRoutingStep, 
          StepOrder,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workorderkey ORDER BY StepOrder) as RowNumber
       from tblFAWOWarrantyRoutingsOEM WarrantyRoutings
       where StepCompleteDate IS NULL
    ) t
WHERE
    t.RowNumber = 1
```

Without window functions you can still do:

```
SELECT wr2.*
FROM
    (
       select
          workorderkey,
          MIN(StepOrder) as MinStepOrder
       from tblFAWOWarrantyRoutingsOEM WarrantyRoutings
       where StepCompleteDate IS NULL
       GROUP BY
          workorderkey
    ) t
    INNER JOIN tblFAWOWarrantyRoutingsOEM wr2
    On t.workorderkey = wr2.workorderkey
    AND StepCompleteDate IS NULL
```

But the latter method could still end up with ties if Step Order is not unique per work order.

Comment: wont he still get the null here which is in his question

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik there is no null in his question anywhere not in either image of data or desired data or narrative!

Comment: not sure why that is in the ops question"SQL return the minium value when another field is null", thats why i put and not steporder is null

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik so you are right there is reference to null but in another field which I would assume is StempCompleteDate which is in the where condition.

Comment: well i will let the op approve you if he disappears comment me back, i didnt want to confuse him with row number, and your 2nd solution might have issues like you said

Answer (score -2):

```
select 
     min(StepOrder),
     workorderkey,
     WarrantyRoutingStep
 from tblFAWOWarrantyRoutingsOEM WarrantyRoutings
 where StepCompleteDate IS NULL
 GROUP BY workorderkey, WarrantyRoutingStep
```

This will work for You

Comment: WarramtyRoutingStep has multiple unique values per workorder key so this route wont work